# Html.imageGetter don't show img in Base64 android

Tags: android, base64

I am trying to show a img in Base64 with Html.fromHtml

I have a tag  with Base64 string of one image.

That is my code:

```
public class GlossaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ...
    private Resources res;

    public GlossaryAdapter(Context context, ...) {
        this.res = context.getResources();
        ...
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ...
        holder.tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(glossary.getContent(), new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {            
                try {
                     byte[] data;
                     data = Base64.decode(source,Base64.DECODE);
                     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);    
                     return new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }, null));
```

glossary.getContent() contains:

```
<img src="AAAY5671NF..." />
```

I tested this string in a html page and works. Show the image.

I am using Android 1.6. 
And this Base64 class: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

I got no errors. But nothing is showing. 
If I change the return to 'null' I got a small gray square.

any ideas?

Comment: somebody? I do 'bitmap.getWidth()' and 'bitmap.getHeight()' and got correct width and height of image. But when I use bitmap got a NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time...
get imageBytes(BLOB) from db.
Enconde to Base64 and pass to src.
Decode and set bounds of bitmap.
Works!

```
@Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {            
            try {
                 byte[] data;
                 data = Base64.decode(source,Base64.DECODE);
                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);    
                 Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
                 d.setBounds(0,0,72,72)   // <-----
                 return d;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```